# Does pytest support the use of function factories in test files?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

Example `test.py` file:

```
import torch

def one():
    return torch.tensor(0.0132005215)

def two():
    return torch.tensor(4.4345855713e-05)

def three():
    return torch.tensor(7.1525573730e-07)


def test_method(method, expected_value):
    value = method()
    assert(torch.isclose(value, expected_value))

def test_one():
    test_method(one, torch.tensor(0.0132005215))

def test_two():
    test_method(two, torch.tensor(4.4345855713e-05))

def test_three():
    test_method(three, torch.tensor(7.1525573730e-07))
    # test_method(three, torch.tensor(1.0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_one()
    test_two()
    test_three()
```

Basically, I have a few functions I want to test (here called `one`, `two` and `three`), all with the same signature but different internals. Thus instead of writing functions `test_one()`, `test_two()`, etc. and thus duplicating code, I wrote a "function factory" (is this the right term?) `test_method`, which takes as an input the function, the expected results and returns the result of an `assert` command.

As you can see, right now the tests are performed manually: I run the script `test.py`, look at the screen, and if no `Assertion error` gets printed, I'm happy. Of course I'd like to improve on this by using `pytest`, since I've been told it's one of the simplest and most used Python testing frameworks. The problem is that by looking at `pytest` [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#run-multiple-tests) I got the impression that `pytest` will try running all functions whose name starts with `test_`. Of course, testing `test_method` itself doesn't make any sense. Can you help me refactor this test script, so that I can run it with `pytest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pytest, you can use [test parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) to achieve this. In your case you have to provide the varying parameters to the test:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("method, expected_value",
                         [(one, 0.0132005215),
                          (two, 4.4345855713e-05),
                          (three, 7.1525573730e-07)])
def test_method(method, expected_value):
    value = method()
    assert(torch.isclose(value, expected_value))
```

If you run `python -m pytest -rA` (see [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#detailed-summary-report) for output options), you will get the output of three tests, something like:

```
======================================================= PASSES ========================================================
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
PASSED test.py::test_method[one-0.0132005215]
PASSED test.py::test_method[two-4.4345855713e-05]
PASSED test.py::test_method[three-7.152557373e-07]
================================================== 3 passed in 0.07s ==================================================
```

if you don't like the fixture names, you can adapt them:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("method, expected_value",
                          [(one, 0.0132005215),
                          (two, 4.4345855713e-05),
                          (three, 7.1525573730e-07),
                          ],
                         ids=["one", "two", "three"])
...
```

This gives you instead:

```
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
PASSED test.py::test_method[one]
PASSED test.py::test_method[two]
PASSED test.py::test_method[three]
================================================== 3 passed in 0.06s ==================================================
```

Comment: actually, `pytest` is only showing me a message that all tests passed, but not a report with the fixture names, like the one you're showing. I'm simply calling `pytest` from the command line. Do I need to pass some command line argument?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I actually used the ouput of a custom test runner. I changed the answer to show the output of `pytest -rA`, which gives the output of each test in the summary.